# R data.table: Count events since last occurance (multiple, inclusive/exclusive)

Tags: r, count, data.table

[udpated: tried to clarify and simplify, corrected sample code and data.]

I've a set of measurements that are taken over a period of days. The range of numbers that can be captured in any measurement is 1-25 (in real life, given the test set, the range could be as high as 100 or as low as 20).

I'd like a way to tally a count for how many events have passed since a specific number occurred regardless of the measurement column. I'd like it to reset the count after the number match as shown below.

V1,V2,Vn are the values captured.
Match1, Match2, Matchn are the counts since last encountered columns.

Note: Matchn counts are incremented regardless of which Vx column n is encountered.

Any help is much appreciated.

this is somewhat related to my earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125656/r-data-table-count-occurrences-prior-to-current-measurement)

**Sample input**

```
library(data.table)
t <- data.table(
  Date = as.Date(c("2013-5-1", "2013-5-2", "2013-5-3", "2013-5-4", "2013-5-5", "2013-5-6", "2013-5-7", "2013-5-8", "2013-5-9", "2013-5-10")),
  V1 = c(4, 2, 3, 1,7,22,35,3,29,36),
  V2 = c(2, 5, 12, 4,8,2,38,50,4,1)
)
```

**code for creating Sample output**

```
t$match1 <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1)
t$match2 <- c(1,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4)
t$match3 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2)

> t
          Date V1 V2 match1 match2 match3
 1: 2013-05-01  4  2      1      1      1
 2: 2013-05-02  2  5      2      1      2
 3: 2013-05-03  3 12      3      2      3
 4: 2013-05-04  1  4      4      3      1
 5: 2013-05-05  7  8      1      4      2
 6: 2013-05-06 22  2      2      5      3
 7: 2013-05-07 35 38      3      1      4
 8: 2013-05-08  3 50      4      2      5
 9: 2013-05-09 29  4      5      3      1
10: 2013-05-10 36  1      1      4      2
```

Comment: I still don't get how you come up with the values for `match1`, `match2`, and `match3` from this post...

Comment: Match1 is looking for a 1 in the "current" row regardless of column (V1, V2). If there is a 1 then the count in Match1 will reset either on that event (row) for exclusive or the following event.

Comment: Okay. For *inclusive*, first match happens at row 4. The reset happens at row 5. And the second match happens at row 10. But the reset happens at row 10... How do you decide whether to reset on the same row or the next row (for *inclusive* alone, for now)?

Comment: `t` is a *really* bad name for a variable. Lookup `?t`! :-)

Comment: a side comment - use `t[, match1 := ...]` instead of `t$match1 = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP has a bunch of typos in it, and as far as I understand you want this:

```
t <- data.table(
  Date = as.Date(c("2013-5-1", "2013-5-2", "2013-5-3", "2013-5-4", "2013-5-5", "2013-5-6", "2013-5-7", "2013-5-8", "2013-5-9", "2013-5-10")),
  V1 = c(4, 2, 3, 1,7,22,35,52,29,36),
  V2 = c(2, 5, 2, 4,8,47,38,50,4,1)
)

t[, inclusive.match.1 := 1:.N, by = cumsum(V1 == 1 | V2 == 1)]
t[, exclusive.match.1 := 1:.N, by = rev(cumsum(rev(V1 == 1 | V2 == 1)))]
t
#          Date V1 V2 inclusive.match.1 exclusive.match.1
# 1: 2013-05-01  4  2                 1                 1
# 2: 2013-05-02  2  5                 2                 2
# 3: 2013-05-03  3  2                 3                 3
# 4: 2013-05-04  1  4                 1                 4
# 5: 2013-05-05  7  8                 2                 1
# 6: 2013-05-06 22 47                 3                 2
# 7: 2013-05-07 35 38                 4                 3
# 8: 2013-05-08 52 50                 5                 4
# 9: 2013-05-09 29  4                 6                 5
#10: 2013-05-10 36  1                 1                 6
```

Comment: is there a way to do that across all of the matchx columns?

Comment: @eAndy sure, use a loop (pick range appropriately): `for (i in 1:3) t[, paste0('inclusive.match.', i) := 1:.N, by = cumsum(V1 == i | V2 == i)]`